Flutter App onclick code not passing value to seperate class file
I am trying to pass a value from my homepage.dart to one of my other dart files with a class. however it doesn't seem to be passing updating the value nor does it look like its entering the class - Homepage.dart
I tried thus far removing the underscore _ from one of the classnames but didn't seem to work. Any help would be really appreciated!
 onTap: () {
                             print('ive been clicked');
                             ListBuilder(
                               refreshCallback: refreshList,
                               collectiontype: 'Today',
                            );
                           },

--- When homepage.dart is starting this automatically starts -
ListBuilder(
                  refreshCallback: refreshList,
                  collectiontype: 'All',
                ),
              ),


list_builder.dart file
    class ListBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback refreshCallback;
  String collectiontype;

  ListBuilder({required this.refreshCallback, required this.collectiontype});

  @override
  _ListBuilderState createState() => _ListBuilderState();
}

class _ListBuilderState extends State<ListBuilder> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> tasks = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchTasks();
  }

Future<void> _fetchTasks() async {
    print('fetching tasks');
    print(widget.collectiontype);
    final database = await openMyDatabase();

    if (widget.collectiontype == 'All') {
      final List<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchedTasks =
          await database.query('tasks');

      print('detected all tasks');

      print(tasks);

      setState(() {
        tasks = fetchedTasks;
      });
    } else if (widget.collectiontype == 'Today') {
      print('detected today tasks');
      await gettasksfortoday();
    }
  }


Debug Console -
Restarted application in 839ms.
I/flutter ( 5733): fetching tasks
I/flutter ( 5733): All

Debug Console when button is clicked -
D/EGL_emulation( 5733): app_time_stats: avg=69.84ms min=10.57ms max=2098.35ms count=39
I/flutter ( 5733): ive been clicked


You cannot pass values to Stateful or Stateless widgets directly as you did. You have to navigate to that class to pass the value.
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ListBuilder(
refreshCallback: refreshList,
collectiontype: 'Today',
) ));
